# Netsuite formula for randomizing numbers

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

Is there a formula I can use in a saved search to randomize numbers in Netsuites. Like the excel formula =RANDBETWEEN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetSuite runs on an Oracle database so you can use the `DBMS_RANDOM` package for this

E.g `ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(10, 20))` will give you a random integer number between 10 and 20, similar to Excel's `=RANDBETWEEN(10,20)`

You can read the official documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_random.htm